# AngularJS routing issue: Home page is not displayed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, ngroute

I am practicing with very simple website using AngularJS. I have made controller to work and now I am implementing routing. It should be simple and I have done in many times in  Codecademy.com, but this time home.html code does not appear on the screen. Folder structure and full code can be found [here](https://github.com/LaurynasGiriunas/EventsApp). Maybe someone knows what is the problem?

My index.html is;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>EventsApp</title>

<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular-route.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body ng-app="EventsApp" ng-controller="HomeController" >
  <header class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <h1 class="col-sm-8">EventsApp</h1>
    </div>
  </header>

<section class="jumbotron">
</section>


<h1>  {{test}}  </h1>
<div ng-view></div>


<!-- Modules -->
<script type="text/javascript"  src="js/app.js"></script>

<!-- Controllers -->
<script type="text/javascript"  src="js/controllers/HomeController.js"></script>

<!-- Services -->

</body>
</html>
```

app.js file:

```
var app = angular.module("EventsApp", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) { 
  $routeProvider 
    .when('/', { 
      controller: 'HomeController', 
      templateUrl: 'views/home.html' 
    }) 
    .otherwise({ 
      redirectTo: '/'
    }); 
});
```

HomeController.js:

```
app.controller('HomeController', ['$scope',
 function($scope) {
    $scope.test="Success";
}]);
```

And home.html:

```
<h1>  {{test}}  </h1>
<section class="container">
  <h1>  {{test}}  </h1>
<div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="card">

          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/red-eye-photography/p1.jpg" />
        <div class="block">
          <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="..." >
        <div class="block">
          <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your scripts should be imported in the `<head>` tag on your index.html, not after the content:

```
<head>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/HomeController.js"></script>
</head>
```

Also, you don't need to set `ng-controller="HomeController"` in your `<body>` tag, as it will be set only for the view by `ngRoute`:

```
$routeProvider.when('/', { 
    controller: 'HomeController', 
    templateUrl: 'views/home.html' 
});
```

Comment: Interesting, this is not how I was taught to import modules and controllers, but it still doesn't look to work...(I had ng-controller="HomeController", just to confirm that the controller is working and that there are no problems with it)

Answer (score 0):

Remember Always scripts must be imported in head tag.
In your case you need to add these in index.html page under head tag as shown

```
<head>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/HomeController.js">    </script>
```

Secondly, you need to add

```
<a href="#/">Home</a>
```

in index.html file.This defines link for your home.html page.
Then you need to update section tag in home.html page as:

```
<section class="container" ng-controller="HomeController">
```

This will tell your home.html page to use "HomeController". No need to write HomeController in  tag of index.html page.

Hope this helps!.

Comment: I am not sure about this. I am not pressing any button that I would need "href" and app.js should use HomeController for the whole home.html page anyway

Answer (score 0):

I have to apologize for this question. The problem was that this was supposed to be a final Codecademy project. Previous projects were done in their system and this was the first project to be done on my own computer. As a newbie I did not know that to test AngularJS projects, local server has to be created. Codecademy project description and step by step guide did not tell this either. It said only to launch html on the browser. At the moment they should be fixing this problem of their step by step guide. Thank you for patience.